# jQuery Ajax not working on second occurence

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I can't fathom what's causing this error, I've tried everything I can think of to fix it. I have two different `submit` buttons, designed to fire some Ajax and post data, on my page. One works and fires perfectly. The second never `POST`s anything.

Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong?

```
$('.delete').submit( function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).children('input[type=\"submit\"]').prop('disabled',true);
    alert("Click detected!");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/deleteWork.php',
        data: slideID,
        type: 'POST',
        mode: 'abort',
        success: function(){
            $('#newOrder-1').fadeOut('fast');
        },
        error: function(){
            $(this).children('input[type=\"submit\"]').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've tried removing the first occurrence, in case it was causing the problem by clashing somehow. I've checked and re-checked my syntax. The `alert` fires fine... just no sign of a POST in Firebug. I don't understand it!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: make an `alert` within `$ajax` success function and what is `slideID`, but I think `slideID` is not matter

Comment: `slideID` is a `hidden` input within the form.

Comment: I tried putting the alert in the $.ajax, and also in the Success and Error sections. No sign :(

Comment: can you post the buttons' markup too?

Comment: $.ajax({ ... mode: 'abort' ... })?  I'm not familiar with this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*smacks forehead*

I needed to add the following line:

```
var slideID = $('#slideID').val();
```

Thanks Aaron W. and thecodeparadox.

Comment: Because the data value was declared on that one. Really dumb mistake by me.

Comment: Do you get reputation points for answering your own question?

Comment: No. You only get points if people upvote your answer. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer